# Average values of precision, recall and fscore for each label

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, cross-validation, precision-recall

I'm cross validating a sklearn classifier model and want to quickly obtain average values of precision, recall and f-score.
How can I obtain those values?

I don't want to code the cross validation by myself, instead I'm using the function cross_validation.cross_val_score. 
Is it possible to use this function to obtain the intended averaged values for each label, by supplying an adequate scoring function?

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it fits your need you take it of from unanswered questions. or comment the answer so that i can complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider using all the method in [sklearn.metrics package](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.metrics).

I think [this method](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support.html#sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support) could do the work you expect. It gives you a 2D array with one row for each target unique value and columns for precision, recall, fscore and support.

For fast logging you can use [classification_report](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html#sklearn.metrics.classification_report) too.

Answer (score 0):

For precision and recall, in the metrics package there is a function called [precision_recall_curve](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve.html) that should do what you're looking for.

Assuming you have a trained classifier `clf`, test exemplars `X` and test targets `Y`, then you'll need to pass the targets and predicted class probabilities. The following example will find precision and recall for a two class problem.

```
probs = clf.predict_proba(X)[:,1]
precision, recall, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(Y, probs)
```

The F-score can be found using a different function in the metrics package, [f1_score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html). This is used in a similar way, but requires the predicted class 
membership as an argument, rather than the probability of membership.